# Can Controllers specify which Interceptors to use

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

I'm moving an existing [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) (3.1.1) web mvc `Controller` (called `LoginController`) to using annotations, I had

```
<bean id="loginHandlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="licenseInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="propertyInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="urlMap">
        <map>
        <!-- used to include references to my LoginController -->
            <entry key="error" value-ref="error" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="order">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I changed my `LoginController` to be annotated. Some other classes had also been annotated previously so it will use the existing...

```
<bean id="requestMappingHandlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="licenseInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="loginInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="propertyInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`LoginController` cannot use the `loginInterceptor` that others use however as it's a pre-login `Controller` but a post-login `Interceptor`.

What I want to know, is there a way to tell Spring that this specific `Controller` should NOT be used with a specific (`loginInterceptor`) `Interceptor`?  And perhaps if it (and only it) could also use `localeChangeInterceptor`.

**What have I tried**

- (works in Spring 3.2) Adding `<mvc:interceptors>` and their namespace to config but they don't seem to allow multiple bean references and `exclude-mapping` is Spring 3.2, I'm 3.1.1
- Doing the processing in `LoginInterceptor`, handler is not of type `LoginController` - I can do `((HandlerMethod)handler).getBean() instanceof LoginController` and that works but it's not pretty or flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what it took to get this working in the `LoginController`.  A little like the solution of @blank but with some other nonsence, I'd still like to have a spring (annotation or config) way of fixing this though

```
public final boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod &&
      ((HandlerMethod)handler).getBean() instanceof LoginController)
    {
      return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using the spring `mvc`namespace you could do the following:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
  <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/login"/>
    <ref bean="loginInterceptor"/>
  </mvc:interceptor>
  <!-- .. further interceptors -->
</mvc:interceptors>
```

this allows to add paths that should not be intercepted by a specific interceptor.

add the `mvc` namespaces to your configuration root element..

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

... and the schema ...

```
xsi:schemaLocation=" .....
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
...."
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't like "/login" as an argument to path: `Invalid content was found starting with element 'mapping'`

Comment: I have updated my answer, you'll need to add the namespace to your configuration xml file

Comment: Added them, still the same result.  If I use your config exactly I get the error at the `exclude-mapping` line

Comment: referring to your post update you're missing the `mvc`namespace => `<mapping ...` -> `<mvc:mapping ...`

Comment: could you add the whole config file please and your the spring version you are using

Comment: The config file is huge and I'm using Spring 3.1.1

Comment: you could set the interceptors explicitly for each url pattern (without `exclude-mapping`)

Comment: Seems I can only `ref` one `intercepter` per `mapping` :(

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past by implementing it in the preHandle method in a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`.

```
@Override
public final boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
   // inspect handler object to see if it's LoginController
}
```

Comment: I thought about this but isn't there a way to do it in Spring config?

Comment: Not that I could find

Comment: Ok, so what's this `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`? because in the `preHandle` of `LoginController` the handlers type is `class org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod`

Comment: I can kind of do this but why would I need to do `((HandlerMethod)handler).getBean() instanceof LoginController` to get it's type?!